# Traduction de « driving force »

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, science

Peut-on traduire en français la phrase suivante :

> Temperature difference is the driving force for heat transfer

par

> La différence de température est la force motrice pour le transfert de chaleur.

L'expression « force motrice » semble être du « franglais ».
Y a-t-il une variation plus francisée et idiomatique ?

Comment: On utilise "Force motrice" en français. Mais la signification est différente, il s'agit d'un terme de physique. Dans ce contexte, on utilisera plutot "le moteur de ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je traduirais par :

> La différence de température joue un rôle moteur dans le transfert de chaleur.

Answer (score 3):

On pourrait dire simplement :

> La différence de température est **le moteur** du transfert de chaleur.

ou bien :

> Le transfert thermique est proportionnel à la différence de température.

Comment: **Proportionnel** a un sens mathématique précis .. pas sûr qu'il soit juste ici ..

Comment: Pour rebondir sur la remarque de MrSmith: Être le moteur de quelque chose est complètement différent d'y être proportionnel. Pour moi, la deuxième phrase est fausse.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington: Tout à fait, cela a un sens précis, et le transfert thermique est effectivement proportionnel au delta des températures

Comment: @Améraldor: C'est plutôt le sens technique, dans le sens où la différence de température **provoque/induit** *de façon automatique* le transfert de chaleur, le transfert est une *conséquence* de la différence de température.

Answer (score 1):

Dans le *Dictionnaire Malgorn des Sciences et Techniques* (Dunod, 6e édition), on peut voir (page 137; version : anglais en français) que l'expression **driving force** peut bien être traduite par « force motrice » (ou bien « poussée »).

Le [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/) (merci@ Jardin de frosted flakes) donne 2 fiches pour driving force qui elles donnent les deux termes dont je parle; voir aussi au [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DRIVING%20FORCE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) pour d'autres suggestions selon le contexte.

Le [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=force%20motrice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforce%20motrice%3B%2Cc0) montre cependant un usage diminué.

Comment: Le [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/) donne 2 fiches pour _driving force_ qui elles donnent les deux termes dont vous parlez ; voir aussi au [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DRIVING+FORCE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) pour d'autres suggestions selon le contexte... Merci !